# Express cookieParser() confused

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

Here's the problem, searched everywhere and never found a clear answer. In order for this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('Secret')); <-- "Secret" to actually be secret
```

What do we actually do? I'm a bit confused. Should I use something like this to secure it:

https://github.com/jed/keygrip

Hopefully the question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make up some long string to use there, and don't tell anyone. ;-)

Comment: Seriously that's it! Wow stupid me, and thank you :) Yup I'm a bit new in that stuff.